# NG-Zorro set specific width for options inside the dropdown causes to also set same width to other dropdowns

Tags: javascript, css, angular, ant-design-pro, ng-zorro-antd

I have been using ng-zorro for my angular project, I am using this component: https://ng.ant.design/components/select/en#ng-content

However, I need to set specific with for the options the dropdown displays after it opens, I tried to do this:

```
>    :host ::ng-deep {   .ant-select-dropdown {
>       width: 112px !important;   } }
```

However, this style also applyes to all the other dropdowns, and I only wanted to give this width to just on dropdown, not all.

I have been looking for other alternative instead of ::ng-deep , but couldn't find one.

I really need to apply with to just one dropdown and not all of them, How can I accomplish this without the issue on ::ng-deep ?

Comment: Please don't post the exact same question twice.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NG-Zorro set specific width for options inside the dropdown causes to also set same width to other dropdowns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69308751/ng-zorro-set-specific-width-for-options-inside-the-dropdown-causes-to-also-set-s)

Answer (score 0):

::ng-deep change the style in every component (as you can see) and is deprecated actually (https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep)

You could use ViewEncapsulation.None (documentation : https://angular.io/guide/view-encapsulation)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).